# Does the fps fall due to sudden clock-speed fall or the gpu is the reason behind this?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, performance, intel-core-i7

My laptop has intel i7 8500u with base freq of 1.8 Ghz and turbo boost upto 4 Ghz.While playing different games  suddenly the fps fall tremendously and the laptop itself starts running slowly not only the game.I run the task manager and noticed that the clock spped during this disaster falls upto 0.4 Ghz causing the whole laptop run slowly.My laptop has nvidia mx-130 gpu 4gb.I reset the bios to default settings too.After that another strange thing happene. One game was running smoothly.it was using required amount of cpu and dedicated gpu nvidia mx130.but another was not using the nvidia at all.and that problem kept coming back for that 2nd game.
So is the gpu causing problem here or the processor?what is the solution? Thank you.

Comment: What are temperatures doing? Have you cleaned the fans?

Comment: Temperature of cpu stays below 70 c and its a laptop.i Don't think clearing fan is an option here

Comment: I would say that we are in a blind, you need to check more games; if issue is there with one and not the other. It could be issue with drivers for that game, problem with cooling (dust building), etc...

Comment: @Samia126 You can blow out dust easily with a can of compressed air - I just did this with my laptop and its running 20C to 30C cooler.